# How do you correctly extract all command synopses from manpages in /usr/share/man/man1?

Tags: shell-script, man

I'm trying to extract all *command synopses* from manpages in `/usr/share/man/man1` using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
## synopses - extract all synopses in /usr/share/man/man1

cd /usr/share/man/man1
for i in *.gz; do
    echo "$i:" | sed -E "s/.1.gz|.gz//g"
    man "./$i" | sed -n '/^SYNOPSIS/,/^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/p' | sed -e '1d; $d' | tr -s [:space:]
done
```

...which provides *some* measure of success - I get complete output for commands from *a* to *z*. But I'm also getting many errors on *stderr* using both `for i in ./*.gz; do man "$i"` and `for i in *.gz; do man "./$i"`*as I output to file* (`synopses > file`)<sup>1</sup>:

```
<standard input>:27: expected `;' after scale-indicator (got `o')
<standard input>:29: expected `;' after scale-indicator (got `o')
<standard input>:283: name expected (got `\{'): treated as missing
<standard input>:674: warning: macro `as',' not defined (possibly missing space after `as')
<standard input>:174: name expected (got `\{'): treated as missing
<standard input>:161: warning [p 1, 5.5i]: can't break line
<standard input>:594: warning [p 5, 3.8i, div `an-div', 0.0i]: can't break line
<standard input>:569: warning [p 6, 0.0i]: can't break line
<standard input>:147: warning [p 1, 1.8i]: can't break line
<standard input>:205: warning [p 2, 0.2i]: can't break line
<standard input>:525: warning [p 5, 4.5i]: can't break line
<standard input>:157: warning [p 1, 4.8i]: can't break line
<standard input>:351: warning [p 3, 1.8i, div `an-div', 0.0i]: can't break line
<standard input>:147: a space character is not allowed in an escape name
man: can't open man1/zshmisc.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshexpn.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshparam.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshoptions.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshbuiltins.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshzle.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshcompwid.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshcompsys.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshcompctl.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshmodules.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshcalsys.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshtcpsys.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshzftpsys.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
man: can't open man1/zshcontrib.1: No such file or directory
man: -:423: warning: failed .so request
<standard input>:423: can't open `man1/zshmisc.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:424: can't open `man1/zshexpn.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:425: can't open `man1/zshparam.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:426: can't open `man1/zshoptions.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:427: can't open `man1/zshbuiltins.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:428: can't open `man1/zshzle.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:429: can't open `man1/zshcompwid.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:430: can't open `man1/zshcompsys.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:431: can't open `man1/zshcompctl.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:432: can't open `man1/zshmodules.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:433: can't open `man1/zshcalsys.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:434: can't open `man1/zshtcpsys.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:435: can't open `man1/zshzftpsys.1': No such file or directory
<standard input>:436: can't open `man1/zshcontrib.1': No such file or directory
```

What are those `<standard input>` errors about (something escaped?) and why is `man` ending up not finding some files? How could I make this more robust/efficient?

---

<sup>1. It seems the errors on *stderr* are the same whatever the implementation/solution I use for the same data. It is striking.</sup>

Comment: For _busybox_: `for i in $(busybox --list); do busybox "$i" --help; done 2>&1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You can't just run `man foo.gz`</del> It looks like you *can* run `man foo.1.gz` but using the `-l` seems cleaner. From `man man`:

```
   -l, --local-file
          Activate `local' mode.  Format and display  local  manual  files
          instead  of  searching  through  the system's manual collection.
          Each manual page argument will be interpreted as an nroff source
          file in the correct format.  No cat file is produced.  If '-' is
          listed as one of the arguments, input will be taken from  stdin.
          When  this  option  is  not used, and man fails to find the page
          required, before displaying the error message,  it  attempts  to
          act as if this option was supplied, using the name as a filename
          and looking for an exact match.
```

So, your script should be something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
## synopses - extract all synopses in /usr/share/man/man1

## No need to cd into the directory, you can just use globs     
for i in /usr/share/man/man1/ajc*.gz; do
    ## This will print the name of the command.      
    basename "${i//.1.gz}"
    man -l "$i"  | 
       awk '/^SYNOPSIS/{a=1; getline}
            (/^[a-zA-z0-9_]/ && a==1){a=0} 
            (a==1 && /./){print}' | tr -s [:space:]

done
```

The `awk` command I give works better than your approach (test it on `man ajc` for example) and now also works on multi-line synopses. Most of the errors you see are irrelevant, others were due to the way you were handling file names. Let me know if this one works better.

Comment: @illuminÉ ah! You want those? OK, hang on.

Comment: @illuminÉ I _think_ those are just issues with formatting he output and will depend on things like the size of your terminal. I wouldn't worry about it. Anyway, try the updated version.

Comment: Works nicely! Your intuition was right - man formatting and the size of the terminal. Furthermore, as someone explained to me synopses need not follow a strict grammar, and manuals vary, so there are exceptions such as `bc` for instance with a "syntax" header instead of "synopsis". I find your solution is quite robust otherwise. I was able to figure out that on my system the `as`, `objcopy` and `cpio` commands have the longest synopses. With development and `perl` related doc. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the errors you encounter, those are all addressed here:

```
man man
```

> `MANWIDTH` - If `$MANWIDTH` is set, its value is used as the line length for which manual pages should be formatted.  If it is not set,  manual  pages will  be  formatted  with  a line length appropriate to the current terminal (using an ioctl(2) if available, the value of `$COLUMNS`, or falling  back to 80 characters if neither is available).  Cat pages will only be saved when the default formatting can be used, that is when the terminal line length is between 66 and 80 characters.
>
> `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` - Normally,  when output is not being directed to a terminal (such as to a file or a pipe), formatting characters are discarded  to  make it  easier  to  read the result without special tools.  However, if `$MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` is set to any non-empty value,  these  formatting  characters  are  retained.   This  may be useful for wrappers around man that can interpret formatting characters.
>
> `MAN_KEEP_STDERR` - Normally, when output is being directed to a terminal (usually to a pager), any error output from the command used to produce formatted versions of manual pages is discarded to avoid interfering with the pager's  display.   Programs such as `groff` often produce relatively minor error messages about  typographical  problems  such  as  poor alignment,  which  are  unsightly and generally confusing when dis- played along with the manual page.  However, some users want to see them anyway, so, if `$MAN_KEEP_STDERR` is set to any non-empty value, error output will be displayed as usual.

And now about how you might do the other thing:

I think this does what you want:

```
for f in /usr/share/man/man1/*gz ; do
    man -P "sed -ne '1,/^[Nn]/d;/^ /{H;b}
    /^[Ss]..[Yy]..[Nn]/{g;:n
    N;/\n\(\n\)[^ ].*/!bn;s//\1/
    s/.\x08//g;s/\(\n\)  */\1/g;
    w /dev/stderr' -ne '};/./q'" -l "$f"
done 2>~/file
```

It specifies that `sed` be the `PAGER` and then outputs only the line following *NAME* and those following *SYNOPSIS* until it encounters any other line beginning with anything other than a `<space>`. It prints *nothing* if the first line not beginning with `<space>` that follows *NAME* does not match begin `[Ss][Yy][Nn]`. In every case it quits reading the file altogether on the second line it encounters following *NAME* that does not begin with `<space>`. It clears leading `<spaces>` and all `\b`ackslashes from the output.

I ran it in the `for` loop just now and it looped over my entire `man` library in only a minute.

`man` adjusts its output based on whether it writes to a terminal or a pipe/file. So if you tell it to do that it forgoes the PAGER altogether. That was unexpected. But I tricked it and used sed's `w`rite function to write out to >&2 and redirected that so it was none the wiser.

A note - though - it may be @terdon's is the better way to go. While you can tailor this easier because you get a `sed` per file, and the formatting is a little better because it doesn't try to fit a terminal width, apparently `man` doesn't write those \backslashes to a `|pipe`.

Comment: @illuminÉ What you might find useful is `nl` - it's handy because it works kind of like `grep` but - depending on your regex - rather than returning only the line you specify it instead indents the entire file and numbers only the regex matches. It's also very fast. It's an excellent way to anchor some more in-depth regexes on a second pass at it.